# Windows 10 update to version 1511, 10586 on netbook hogs internet to download, fails to upgrade, downloads again

Tags: windows-10, upgrade, windows-update, infinite-loop

I've got a cheap netbook that **came with Windows 10 installed** (Lenovo Ideapad 100S).

It's now stuck in a resource-hogging loop that downloads the "Upgrade to **Windows 10 Home, version 1511, 10586**" over and over again, failing every time.

[image: screengrap of Windows Update]

Each download seems to take about a day. It's now downloading for the third time.

On an underpowered netbook and not-really-speedy Internet connection, this hogs both bandwidth and CPU. The computer is still usable during each download phase - just compromised.

The first time the download phase completed I was present for the install phase. it failed because the stock drive on the netbook didn't have enough space for the upgrade. It gave me the option to choose a different download location. I told it to use my external 1TB USB hard drive which has tons of space.

The second time the download phase completed I was not present to see the reason the upgrade failed.

I've Googled but only find other kinds of Windows upgrade loop problems.

I'm happy for a solution that **a)** gets the upgrade to work, **b)** stops the computer from retrying it over and over, or **c)** downloads the upgrade just once even if it has to try a couple of times to install it.

Comment: Download the Media Creation Tool, allow it to download the .ISO, then choose "Upgrade Now".  If you can't tell us the reason it failed the second time, not sure what the question is, if you don't have enough space on the system drive use the `Cleanup Tool` and/or use a flash drive to create an .ISO.  The process is the same, this update by the way, more or less installs Windows again so it will take awhile.

Comment: I don't have a flash drive greater than 8gb and I don't want to fork out cash to stop Microsoft's bug. The netbook is brand new and surprisingly comes with zero crapware therefore nothing to clean up that didn't come with Windows 10. I can try the Media Creation Tool and downloading the ISO. It would be great if I could also stop Windows from downloading the update in the meantime though. I suppose that could be a new SU question.

Comment: ["If you run this tool on a PC running Windows 10, it can overwrite temporary files that are needed if you ever want to go back to your previous operating system."](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10)

Comment: What you describe isn't a bug.  Your last comment is confusing.  **You currently can't go back to the previous version of the operating system, there currently isn't a previous version, so there is ability to lose.**

Comment: I wasn't asking about going back to my previous operating system. I was quoting the warning text from the Microsoft tool verbatim. Hence the link and the quotation marks.